# What does it mean when there are two pipes (||) next to each other?

Tags: c#

An example of it in use would be...

```
if (temp < 30 || temp > 90) { MessageBox.Show("Error"); }
```

What do two pipes (||) together mean?

Comment: It means you havent done any research on [C# Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Comment: @Plutonix you comment should be marked as accepted :P

Comment: @Scootaloo Welcome to the SO community! Sorry there's a lot of sarcasm in the comments, but most people try to help. It's just that this is a (relatively) simple idea in programming.

Comment: Why were all of these answers downvoted? They weren't bad answers, were they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pipe is a logical OR operator which always evaluates both operands.

Two pipes is short-circuiting logical OR operator, which only evaluates the second operand if the first one is `false`. This is especially useful if the second operand is a heavy function that you don't want to evaluate unnecessarily or it is something that can throw an exception, e.g.:

```
if(myList == null || myList.Count == 0){
    //do something
}
```

In this example, if `myList` is `null`, the second operand is never evaluated. If we use one pipe instead, the second operand will be evaluated and will throw an exception because `myList` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

A pipe `|` in C# (and many other languages [except when a single pipe is used as a bitwise logical operator, such as in Java]) is the logical operator **OR**.

The double pipe `||` is shortcut OR. It means that if the first is true, then the operation will automatically quit, because one condition is already true. Therefore, OR must be true. (A single `|`, therefore, means that it will check all conditions first before evaluating, which is slower and usually not useful).

In your example:

```
if (temp < 30 || temp > 90) { MessageBox.Show("Error"); }
```

- `temp < 30`: first condition
- `||`: logical OR
- `temp > 90`: second condition

This means, if (the first condition) **OR** (the second condition) is true, then show "Error".